# Fixed width div and float:right; div not working

Tags: html, css

I cannot for the life of me find out why this technique isn’t working. No matter what I do, the left `div` is 100% when it should adjust to the `float:right;` `div`.

```css
.chat-container {
  background: black;
  height: 60px;
}
.chat-bar {
  height: 60px;
  width: 340px;
  float: right;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-bar">

</div>
<div class="chat-container">

</div>
```

Something funny is going on. I followed a tutorial and it is not working, however it works for some other elements. Am I blind?

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: Working: https://jsfiddle.net/jw727odf/

Comment: The red div should not have the black div overlapping under it, They're two side by side divs, but for some reason the black div is 100% in width. Here is a working example of what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/SpSjL/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing:

```
.chat-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/jw727odf/1/

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out. That solved my issue, I seem to be very blind, haha. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a float will remove an element from the normal document flow, so it won't effect the width of the other element. If you want to keep the float you'll need to specify a width for both elements. Try using [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) like so:

```css
.chat-container {
  background: black;
  height: 60px;
  width: calc(100% - 340px);
}
.chat-bar {
  height: 60px;
  width: 340px;
  float: right;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-bar">

</div>
<div class="chat-container">

</div>
```

Or you could set the width of both in percent, but you will lose the fixed width:

```css
.chat-container {
  background: black;
  height: 60px;
  width: 55%;
}
.chat-bar {
  height: 60px;
  width: 45%;
  float: right;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-bar">

</div>
<div class="chat-container">

</div>
```